# Swift 3: Preload SecondViewController's WKWebView ahead of click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, preload, tabbarcontroller

I need some help.
I want to preload my webView in Second View Controller after the webView in the First View Controller is done.

I believe I need to use a notification center post/observe to call my loadWebView-function in my Second View Controller but don't know how. Any suggestions is appreciated.

---

[image]

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit;
import WebKit;

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {


    let webView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("loaded!")
        webView.isHidden = false

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        webView.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

    }

}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let webView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height))


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("loaded!")
        webView.isHidden = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    func loadWebView() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com")
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        webView.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In First VC :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

   //Post notification
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "WebViewFinishedLoading"), object: nil)
}
```

In Second VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   // Add observer for your notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadWebView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "WebViewFinishedLoading"), object: nil)
    }

//Remove observer in deinit
 deinit {    
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
 }
```

Comment: If secondViewController is not in stack then ?

Comment: You can't load it before its initialized. What exactly are you doing?